# Add many pandas dataframes with overlapping indexes and columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

What is the best way provided by pandas to combine many dataframes, and perform mathematical addition of the values at the overlapping rows and columns?

I have a long list of overlapping dataframes that look like this (this is showing only 3 of them):

```
>>> df1
     xcode  ycode
n
17       1      0
18       1      0
19       1      0
20       1      0
21       1      0
389      1      0
390      1      0
391      1      0
392      1      0
393      1      0
394      1      0
>>> df2
     xcode  ycode
n
58       1      0
59       1      0
60       1      0
61       1      0
62       1      0
610      1      0
611      1      0
612      1      0
613      1      0
614      1      0
615      1      0
>>> df3
    xcode  ycode
n
21      0      1
22      0      1
23      0      1
24      0      1
25      0      1
26      0      1
27      0      1
28      0      1
29      0      1
30      0      1
31      0      1
32      0      1
33      0      1
34      0      1
35      0      1
36      0      1
37      0      1
38      0      1
39      0      1
40      0      1
41      0      1
42      0      1
43      0      1
44      0      1
45      0      1
46      0      1
47      0      1
48      0      1
49      0      1
50      0      1
51      0      1
52      0      1
53      0      1
54      0      1
55      0      1
56      0      1
57      0      1
58      0      1
```

I can combine these, adding together the values at the overlapping rows and columns, in the following way, but it is a long bit of code:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame().add(df1, fill_value=0).add(df2, fill_value=0).add(df3, fill_value=0)
     xcode  ycode
n
17       1      0
18       1      0
19       1      0
20       1      0
21       1      1    # Note the overlapping index
389      1      0
390      1      0
391      1      0
392      1      0
393      1      0
394      1      0
58       1      1    # Note the overlapping index
59       1      0
60       1      0
61       1      0
62       1      0
610      1      0
611      1      0
612      1      0
613      1      0
614      1      0
615      1      0
22       0      1
23       0      1
24       0      1
25       0      1
26       0      1
27       0      1
28       0      1
29       0      1
30       0      1
31       0      1
32       0      1
33       0      1
34       0      1
35       0      1
36       0      1
37       0      1
38       0      1
39       0      1
40       0      1
41       0      1
42       0      1
43       0      1
44       0      1
45       0      1
46       0      1
47       0      1
48       0      1
49       0      1
50       0      1
51       0      1
52       0      1
53       0      1
54       0      1
55       0      1
56       0      1
57       0      1
```

I could do the same thing using a loop, or `reduce`. But does the pandas library provide a better way to do this?

(I searched, but could not find a similar question; other questions either have identical indexes, or only a couple of dataframes being added.)

Comment: are you asking about a mathematical addition or a concatenation of the dataframes?

Comment: sorry i guess it isn't clear since it is 1s and 0s: mathematical addition in this case, but it would also be useful if there is a way to do other operations, like perhaps concatenate strings. but for the purposes of this question, yes, addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` and `sum` with `level=0`.

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sum(level=0)    
     xcode  ycode
n
17       1      0
18       1      0
19       1      0
20       1      0
21       1      1
389      1      0
390      1      0
391      1      0
392      1      0
393      1      0
394      1      0
58       1      1
59       1      0
60       1      0
61       1      0
62       1      0
610      1      0
611      1      0
612      1      0
613      1      0
614      1      0
615      1      0
22       0      1
23       0      1
24       0      1
25       0      1
26       0      1
27       0      1
28       0      1
29       0      1
30       0      1
31       0      1
32       0      1
33       0      1
34       0      1
35       0      1
36       0      1
37       0      1
38       0      1
39       0      1
40       0      1
41       0      1
42       0      1
43       0      1
44       0      1
45       0      1
46       0      1
47       0      1
48       0      1
49       0      1
50       0      1
51       0      1
52       0      1
53       0      1
54       0      1
55       0      1
56       0      1
57       0      1
```

Comment: You may want to tag on `.sort_index()` to the result.

Comment: @Alexander: if you check the answer's editing history, you will see my answer has `sort_index` before `sum`. However, Rick edited to take out the `sort_index`. Perhaps, he doesn't want `sort_index`. He also edited the question to reflect unsorted desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use standard python operators:

```
sum([df1, df2, df3])
```

or

```
df1 + df2 + df3
```

Comment: the indexes of the dataframes are not all the same. the resulting dataframe is filled with NaN.

Comment: call .fillna() or .dropna() at the end.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my question (probably my fault), those do not produce the desired output.